# Is it permissible for Muslims to receive subsidy for performing Hajj?

Tags: hajj, loan, five-pillars, government

It's a known fact that Hajj is fard only if one is physically and financially able,

as the Qurán says it in Al-e-imran :

"In it are clear signs, the standing place of Ibrahim, and whoever enters it shall be secure, and pilgrimage to the House is incumbent upon men for the sake of Allah, (upon) **

> every one who is able to undertake the journey to it

**; and whoever disbelieves, then surely Allah is Self-sufficient, above any need of the worlds." 3:97
but ,my question is

"Is Hajj permissible/allowed/halal when the government subsidizes the money required to go to Hajj?"

P.S:Hajj is subsidized in India.
Ministry of Civil Aviation provides subsidy for air travel to the pilgrims through the Haj Committee of India.  The amount on air travel charged per pilgrim during Haj 2014 was Rs. 35,000/-(529.874 US Dollar) whereas the actual air fare ranged from Rs. 63,750(965.13 US Dollar) to Rs. 1,63,350(2473 US Dollar) depending on the embarkation point in India.

Edit:No,its not a debt.

Comment: Could you elaborate the question a bit more. E.g. how do they subsidize it? And what do you mean by "Hajj is subsidized"? It would be great if you would mention your own research efforts in this respect.

Comment: If the money isn't a debt then sure you can use it for hajj.

Comment: Well i know that in some Arabic countries clerks could get the Hajj as a gift from Government, so as Sayyid said as long as this money isn't a debt that would be fine! Else you should edit your Question and explain what you mean as Bleeding Fingers suggested!

Comment: @BleedingFingers edited the question..

Comment: It's not something you have to give back, so use it and I hope you pray for us during hajj.

Answer (score 1):

That depends from what sources and terms the government is giving those subsidies.

- If the source and terms are of [zakat](/questions/tagged/zakat), then it's not permissible<sup>1</sup> to accept the subsidy as, by default, those going to hajj are rich and themselves are subject to give zakat.
- If the source and terms are of [sadaqah](/questions/tagged/sadaqah) or gift, then it is OK to receive the subsidy and benefit from it.

<sup>1</sup> http://quran.com/9/60

> SAHIH INTERNATIONAL
>
> Zakah expenditures are only for the poor and for the needy and for those employed to collect [zakah] and for bringing hearts together [for Islam] and for freeing captives [or slaves] and for those in debt and for the cause of Allah and for the [stranded] traveler - an obligation [imposed] by Allah. And Allah is Knowing and Wise.

Comment: AFAIK there might be even no Muslim country where the government is collecting sadaqah or zakat, therefore i would wonder more how this could apply to India, where Muslims are a "minority"!

Comment: @Medi1Saif they can look up the terms then, no? If the subsidy is a gift, then I don't see why one would not accept it.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, does not the second bullet point already cover that?